# In Angularjs which of ng-clikc and href has higher priority

Tags: ionic-framework, href, angularjs-ng-click

Let's say that i have this tag :

```
      <a ng-click="leavingMenuPage()" href="#/app/interview" >
        <i class="icon ion-android-person"></i>
        <p class="pFont" >Görüşme</p>
      </a>
```

Does ng-click will be called first or it will go to the link defined before ??

Comment: JS is first. You can understand it just in fact, that if you call e.preventDefault() - you dont leave the page.

Comment: But if you dont use preventDefault - firstly will be called JS, and then - redirect.